# A Kingly Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> I am sometimes meant to educate,
>
> Sixteen against but my size is just eight,
>
> Warfare recorded a few letters at a time,
>
> But death over me considered a crime,
>
> I'm French or Scandinavian in my opening days,
>
> But the world can participate, in their own ways,
>
> I consistently prize skill over dice,
>
> Not ritual, but sacrifice.

### What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> Chess.

I am sometimes meant to educate

> Many students, especially children, study chess to learn strategy and critical thinking as an extracurricular

Sixteen against but my size is just eight,

> There are sixteen pieces on each side, but the board is 8x8

Warfare recorded a few letters at a time,

> The game simulates war, and the moves can be referred to as their rank and file on the board (e.g. "knight to B8")

But death over me considered a crime,

> Well, you shouldn't murder anyone over a board game.

I'm French or Scandinavian in my opening days,

> There are famous French and Scandinavian [Chess Openings.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_openings), such as the [French Defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Defence).

But the world can participate, in their own ways,

> The game is played globally, with strategies, like those openings, hailing from all over

I consistently prize skill over dice,

> Chess is a game of skill and strategy with no element of chance

Not ritual, but sacrifice.

> In Chess, it may be a winning play to sacrifice some of your pieces to threaten the enemy and win the game

Title: A Kingly Riddle

> Chess is all about the King.  Whomsoever mates his opponent's King first wins.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Fluid ounce?

I am sometimes meant to educate,

> 8 fl oz per cup, 2 cups per pint, etc.

Sixteen against but my size is just eight,

> 16 referencing to weight ounces, whereas 8 is fluid ounces.

Warfare recorded a few letters at a time,

> oz, lb, etc.

But death over me considered a crime,

> Killing someone over a cup of sugar, etc.

I'm French or Scandinavian in my opening days,

> Not sure, perhaps the word origin?

But the world can participate, in their own ways,

> Baking, cooking, etc.

I consistently prize skill over dice,

> Baking is more science than art, hence why everything is measured by ounce.

Not ritual, but sacrifice.

> This could be referring to donating blood, as it is done by the pint or 16 fluid ounces.

Title: A Kingly Riddle

> Reference to the Imperial System, which is what the fluid ounce is part of.